# meaning of "on bequest of "

Tags: meaning

What's the meaning of "on bequest of" in this phrase

Context: [Democracy and the Limits of Self-Government
 By Adam Przeworski](http://goo.gl/bw76rQ)

> We are ruled by others, and the only authority that justifies this fact is that the rulers act on bequest of “the people” expressed in elections

Does it mean "at the request of"?

Comment: I think that's a malapropism for *on behalf of*, or a portmanteau of *request* and *behalf*. I'm sure [bequest](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bequest) can't be used like that.

Comment: I was sure it could not either but I changed my mind after googling it. See my answer

Comment: Just because it's in a published work doesn't make it right!

Comment: But it is in MANY published works - especially legal ones

Comment: OED doesn't list it, but it did remind me of *behest*. I still reckon it's a malapropism (however widely adopted).

Comment: I cannot find the meaning in wikipedia or MW so I tend to agree. When I read the paragraph in the book where the sentence come from, the author makes a distinct difference between the bequest and behalf of.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: I'm not sure I understand your last comment properly. I've just had a look at the OED (1994 edition) and it says for "bequest": "*The act of bequeathing; transference or bestowal by will, or by a similar procedure.*". But I do agree that in OP's example the word is not used properly.

Comment: @Laure Online OED mentions *behest* as having an analogous etymology. *At the behest of* would also fit in the sentence instead of *on bequest of*.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: my CDrom edition of the OED gives different etymology for both words but signals for *bequeath* a "later change parallel to that of behest" which  I understand (I might be wrong) as bequeath→bequest as an imitation in the spelling.

Comment: @Laure Yes, that's what I meant by analogous. Similar changes occurred in both words [at different times, and possibly for different reasons].

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about either a typo or a "portmanteau malapropism" deriving from *behest, request,  **behalf***.

Answer (score 1):

After having a long look at Google and read the paragraph you are referring to (and that I added to your question) I believe it means the following:

That the rulers have been allowed to rule by the people's votes - that the people endow - bequest - the authority with the power to take decisions on their behalf

Please note that to bequeath is leaving something by will/testament so it is possible that the above is a malapropism as stated by Andrew Leach.